# Should my new item already be in the mapped to directory before i add it to tfs?

Tags: tfs

In our environment we don't add solutions to TFS, just individual items to a specific tfs folder.  I'm preparing to add my first item to the TFS folder.  The TFS folder is already mapped to a personal work directory on our dev server. With the goal being that future "get latests" will map this new item to the same work directory on the dev server, is it better if I place the new item in that mapped directory and then add the item from there in tfs (rt click ->add item)?  Or just add item in TFS from a location the new item currently sits in , one that is unknown to TFS?  I am concerned if I add it from the mapped to location that TFS will get confused and create a version number on this item in the future.  And that if I add it from its current location, tfs will map there in the future when it comes to "getting" this item out of source control.

I haven't tried anything yet but the item is ready for checking in.  I did have to change something recently and in that case I checked that item out right from TFS and then opened it in notepad in the work directory, then pasted the new code, then closed and then checked it in to TFS right in TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click in TFS's white area that represents your target source control location, choose add item and point anywhere you like for the new item's current location.  What TFS apparently does is add it to your mapped local directory for you before showing it as a TFS check in candidate with a green plus sign.  You right click the item with green plus sign and check in like you would anything else.  In our case that includes adding a comment and then hitting the check in button.  I checked the mapped local directory and it is there.